# javascript и mongodb: Cannot read property 'insertOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Есть проблема, в файле db.js есть такой код:

```js
const mc = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

function connect(uri) {
    var client = new mc(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    client.connect(err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        db = client.db("test").collection("test");
        console.log("Connected");
    });
}

function insert(data) {
    db.insertOne(data, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("Inserted " + data);
    });
}

module.exports.connect = connect;
module.exports.insert = insert;
```

Но при запуске из другого файла (

```
const db = require('./db');
db.connect();
db.insert({testing: true});
```

)

происходит ошибка: `Cannot read property 'insertOne' of undefined`
В базу данных ничего не кладётся, код завершается.
Буду рад, если подскажете, где ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде переменная `db` объявляется всего два раза:

1. Это глобально, без присвоения ей какого либо значения:

```js
const mc = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;
```

2. В функции `connect`

```js
        db = client.db("test").collection("test");
        console.log("Connected");
```

Поэтому когда вы вызываете функцию insert , в которой параметр `bd` не определен, javascript берет его из глобальной области видимости, но там Вы не задали ему какое-либо значение, а проста задекларировали переменную используя `var`, поэтому значение у нее `undefined`. Что бы поправить ошибку поместите `db = client.db("test").collection("test");` в тело функции `insert`

Comment: Да, вы правы, ещё нужно вынести `var client = new MongoClient(config.db.uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });` за функцию connect.